# How to restart a failed task on Airflow and keep the failure record?

Tags: airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs, airflow-scheduler

My DAG looks like this:

task1 >> task2 >> task3

and task2 has failed.
I would like to restart the dagrun from the last failure point which is task2, and I understand I can use "clear" for that.

The issue is that when I use clear the execution attempt is cleared and looking back I have no record of this failure anymore.

I'm wondering if I can rerun, but still keep the failure history.

Comment: The failure is registered in the Log.
Choose the task which you retry and go to the log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The failure data is available in a tab inside the log.

For example, if I have auto retries set to 3 and all 3 fail, there will be 3 tabs in the Airflow UI Logs.

Similarly, restarting a failed task will log the new runs in a new tab.

It will be under the heading of "Log by attempts".

Of course this also means that you can view them in the actual log files themselves. There is a attempt numbering in the log file to indicate the divide between attempts.